# Linking two nodes in two different random networks in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I have created two random (Erdos-Renyi) networks using R (and the igraph package), that have 10 nodes each. Each node, in both the networks, has been randomly assigned with an attribute of either 0 or 1.

Here is my code to do this:

```
# Creates the first Erdos-Renyi graph, graph_a, with 10 nodes and edges with
# p=0.2
num_nodes <- 10
prob <- 0.2
graph_a <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, prob, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
    directed=FALSE, loops=FALSE)

# Randomly sets the attributes of the nodes of graph_a to either 0 or 1
graph_a <- set.vertex.attribute(graph_a, "value", 
    value = sample(0:1, num_nodes, replace=TRUE))


# Creates the second Erdos-Renyi graph, graph_b, with 10 nodes and edges with 
# p=0.2
graph_b <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, prob, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
    directed=FALSE, loops=FALSE)

# Randomly sets the attributes of the nodes of graph_b to either 0 or 1
graph_b <- set.vertex.attribute(graph_b, "value", 
    value = sample(0:1, num_nodes, replace=TRUE))
```

I need to somehow link a randomly selected node from the first graph, to a randomly selected node from the second graph. So if the 0 or 1 attribute value of the selected node from the first graph changes, the attribute value of the selected node from the second graph should also change (and vice versa).

Could anyone suggest a solution on how to achieve this?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Remember the solution to the simple majority rule? The answer will be very similar to the part where you checked if the node was going to be udpated.

Comment: This isn't clear. When you say 'link a randomly selected node' from a to b, is picking two random numbers in the range 1:10 enough? How is the attribute value of the first graph changing? These things don't change themselves. Or do you want to add the graphs and then create a set of edges that form a permutation from a to b? Would that do? You can do graph_c = graph_a + graph_b and then add edges.

Comment: @Spacedman - Why would picking a random node from each network not be enough? The attributes change according to the simple majority rule, where a node's attribute is changed from 1 to 0 (or 0 to 1) according to the attributes of the majority of it's neighbors. For example if the majority of a node's  neighbors have the value of 0, the node's value changed to 0, too. I don't what to add the graphs together. O just want to connect two nodes.

Comment: You just need to separate the selection of the random attribute, and setting the node to that value: first, randomly decide whether you're going to change the node to 0, or 1. Then, check whether this will change the node. Then, you can change the attributes for that node in both networks accordingly.

Comment: What? You've just got two graphs with 0 or 1 on each node. Where does this 'majority rule' thing come from? Please add this to the question. Oh, its an earlier question of yours, which I wasn't psychically able to know. So I give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a mapping from nodes in a to nodes in b - it doesn't have to be a permutation, as long as this is a vector of length 10 with entries <= the number of nodes in b that will apply:

```
> perm=sample(10)
> perm
 [1]  7  6  1  8  5 10  2  9  3  4
```

So node 1 in graph a is randomly associated with node 7 of graph b, node 2 of a maps to node 6 of b and so on.

Pick a random node in `graph_a`:

```
> i=sample(10,1)
> i
[1] 7  # 7 was picked
```

Currently its:

```
> V(graph_a)$value[i]
[1] 0
```

So we flip it:

```
> V(graph_a)$value[i] = 1 - V(graph_a)$value[i]
> V(graph_a)$value[i]
[1] 1
```

Which one in b is this mapped to?

```
> perm[7]
[1] 2
```

Currently:

```
> V(graph_b)$value[2]
[1] 1
```

So flip it:

```
> V(graph_b)$value[perm[i]] = 1 - V(graph_b)$value[perm[i]]
> V(graph_b)$value[perm[i]]
[1] 0
```

Job done.

Comment: Answer edited, but if you don't know how to generate a random integer in R then you need to go back to basics.